# Commit -m is not taken into account

Tags: git

When I send the command to commit a version, nothing happens.

```
$ git status

On branch main
Your branch is up to date with `'origin/main'`.

nothing to commit, working tree clean

$ git commit -m "Ajout de la fonction get_soup_file "

On branch main
Your branch is up to date with `'origin/main'`.

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

Why is the commit command not taken into account?

Comment: What do you expect the commit command to do? There are no changes to commit.

Comment: "nothing to commit, working tree clean" no changes, no commit. It doesn't matter if you provide a message or not, you cannot commit if there are no changes

Comment: I have a red dot on VSC terminal...

Comment: I add the files to commit but nothing is working it seems

Comment: There are no changes (as in: 0 changes). Did you save your files?

Comment: indeed I had an issue within saving the file ! Sorry...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not made anything possible to commit. That is, you need to first stage your changes using the git add command. But, in order to be able to use the git add command, you also need to have done some changes and save your changes. This way, when you do git status, you will see that you have modified some files.

Comment: indeed I had an issue within saving the file ! Sorry...

Answer (score 1):

You haven't added any changes to be pushed into the remote location.
When you do a

> git status

you will see some red file names. These need to be 'added' to a commit.

Use:

> git add nameOfFilesYouWantToPush

Then you should be able to do `git commit -m "CommitDescription"`.

Commits are basically when you made changes to your code that you are happy with, and you want to push up those changes into the remote location.